# Redirect if someone try to access my sitemap

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

My sitemap location is on [this link](http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml). this sitemap was generate by plugin and not exists on directory.

I want to redirect to home page or image from other website if someone trying to access, only bot can access it.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(googlebot|msnbot|baiduspider|slurp|webcrawler) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sitemap.xml [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: redirect to your script, which will redirect to specified location or will send your sitemap.xml

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in your htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php [L]
```